# Using GetElementsByClassName to check checkbox values and if the checkbox is checked programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

The task is to write to a string whether a checkbox has been checked out of a series of 27 checkboxes with the same class name of "GEMS_0".

When I access elements through console it works.

```
document.getElementById(document.getElementsByClassName("GEMS_0")[0].id).value
```

returns "moved"

```
document.getElementById(document.getElementsByClassName("GEMS_0")[0].id).value
```

returns false.

When I do it programmatically, by calling getGEMSValue(0), it works for the first element and then returns null for the value of the second element when it should be "filled with wonder". I tried changing to "filled-with-wonder" but that didn't change anything.

Here is the code for accessing the elements programmatically:

```
  function getGEMSValue(num) {
    let return_string = "";
    let checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("GEMS_" + num.toString());
    console.log(checkboxes);
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      console.log(checkboxes[i].id);
      console.log(document.getElementById(checkboxes[i].id));
      let value = document.getElementById(checkboxes[i].id).value
      if (document.getElementById(checkboxes[i].id).checked) {
        return_string += value + ";";
      } else {
        return_string += "false;";
      }
    }
    //remove semicolon at end
    return_string = return_string.slice(0,-1);
    return return_string;
  }
```

This is the HTML being accessed.

```
      <p align="center">How would you describe this video's overall emotion? You may select multiple options.</p>
      <!-- 9 emotions per row, 5 rows -->
      <div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="moved">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">moved</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="filled with wonder">
          <label class="form-check-label GEMS_0" for="inlineCheckbox2">filled with wonder</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="allured">
          <label class="form-check-label GEMS_0" for="inlineCheckbox3">allured</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox4" value="fascinated">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox4">fascinated</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox5" value="overwhelmed">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox5">overwhelmed</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox6" value="feeling of transcendence">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox6">feeling of transcendence</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox7" value="serene">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox7">serene</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox8" value="calm">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox8">calm</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox9" value="soothed">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox9">soothed</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox10" value="tender">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox10">tender</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox11" value="affectionate">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox11">affectionate</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox12" value="mellow">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox12">mellow</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox13" value="nostalgic">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox13">nostalgic</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox14" value="sentimental">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox14">sentimental</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox15" value="dreamy">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox15">dreamy</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox16" value="strong">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox16">strong</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="energetic">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox17">energetic</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox18" value="triumphant">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox18">triumphant</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox19" value="animated">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox19">animated</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox20" value="bouncy">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox20">bouncy</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox21" value="joyful">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox21">joyful</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox22" value="sad">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox22">sad</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox23" value="tearful">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox23">tearful</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox24" value="blue">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox24">blue</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox25" value="tense">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox25">tense</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox26" value="agitated">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox26">agitated</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox27" value="nervous">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox27">nervous</label>
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
```

Comment: can you post enough code to make a working example please?

Comment: You dont need to use `document.getElementById` if you are getting the element by `getElementsByClassName`, you are going to end up with the same dom object

Comment: As @gforce301 stated, please provide more code, namely your HTML that you are analysing.

Comment: Well, I think @PatrickEvans comment fixed it. I'll add the rest anyway, one second

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, `document.getElementById( element.id )` is an anti-pattern and should really just be `element` since `id` should be unique in document.

But for your task, intead of iterating over all the checkboxes, then checking all their `checked` status to compose your string, you can get the same result much faster using a simple [`:checked` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked):

```js
document.getElementById('checker').onclick = (evt) => {
  // select only the checked inputs with class GEMS_0
  const checked_gems = document.querySelectorAll('.GEMS_0:checked');
  // compose your string of values
  const result = [...checked_gems].map( elem => elem.value ).join(';');
  console.log( result );
}
```

```css
body { margin-bottom: 150px; }
```

```html
<p align="center">How would you describe this video's overall emotion? You may select multiple options.</p>
<!-- 9 emotions per row, 5 rows -->
<div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="moved">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">moved</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="filled with wonder">
    <label class="form-check-label GEMS_0" for="inlineCheckbox2">filled with wonder</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="allured">
    <label class="form-check-label GEMS_0" for="inlineCheckbox3">allured</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox4" value="fascinated">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox4">fascinated</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox5" value="overwhelmed">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox5">overwhelmed</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox6" value="feeling of transcendence">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox6">feeling of transcendence</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox7" value="serene">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox7">serene</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox8" value="calm">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox8">calm</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox9" value="soothed">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox9">soothed</label>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox10" value="tender">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox10">tender</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox11" value="affectionate">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox11">affectionate</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox12" value="mellow">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox12">mellow</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox13" value="nostalgic">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox13">nostalgic</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox14" value="sentimental">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox14">sentimental</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox15" value="dreamy">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox15">dreamy</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox16" value="strong">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox16">strong</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="energetic">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox17">energetic</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox18" value="triumphant">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox18">triumphant</label>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox19" value="animated">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox19">animated</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox20" value="bouncy">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox20">bouncy</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox21" value="joyful">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox21">joyful</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox22" value="sad">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox22">sad</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox23" value="tearful">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox23">tearful</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox24" value="blue">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox24">blue</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox25" value="tense">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox25">tense</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox26" value="agitated">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox26">agitated</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox27" value="nervous">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox27">nervous</label>
  </div>
  <br />
</div>
<button id="checker">check selection</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use this code

```
function getGEMSValue(num) {
  let inElm = document.getElementById('inlineCheckbox'+num);

  //... 
  console.log( inElm.id,  inElm.checked, inElm.value );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question mentioned `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Just slight changing to JS of answer by `@Kaiido`

```js
const checkedVals = () => {
    let result = [];
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("GEMS_0")).forEach(elem => elem.checked ? result.push(elem.value) : '');
    console.log(result, result.join(';'));
    // OR
    let result1 = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("GEMS_0")).map(elem => elem.checked ? elem.value : null).filter(x => !!x);
    console.log(result1, result1.join(';'));
};
document.getElementById('checker').onclick = checkedVals;
```

```css
body {
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

```html
<p align="center">How would you describe this video's overall emotion? You may select multiple options.</p>
<!-- 9 emotions per row, 5 rows -->
<div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="moved">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">moved</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="filled with wonder">
    <label class="form-check-label GEMS_0" for="inlineCheckbox2">filled with wonder</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="allured">
    <label class="form-check-label GEMS_0" for="inlineCheckbox3">allured</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox4" value="fascinated">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox4">fascinated</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox5" value="overwhelmed">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox5">overwhelmed</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox6" value="feeling of transcendence">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox6">feeling of transcendence</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox7" value="serene">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox7">serene</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox8" value="calm">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox8">calm</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox9" value="soothed">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox9">soothed</label>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox10" value="tender">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox10">tender</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox11" value="affectionate">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox11">affectionate</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox12" value="mellow">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox12">mellow</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox13" value="nostalgic">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox13">nostalgic</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox14" value="sentimental">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox14">sentimental</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox15" value="dreamy">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox15">dreamy</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox16" value="strong">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox16">strong</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="energetic">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox17">energetic</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox18" value="triumphant">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox18">triumphant</label>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox19" value="animated">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox19">animated</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox20" value="bouncy">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox20">bouncy</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox21" value="joyful">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox21">joyful</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox22" value="sad">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox22">sad</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox23" value="tearful">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox23">tearful</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox24" value="blue">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox24">blue</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox25" value="tense">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox25">tense</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox26" value="agitated">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox26">agitated</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input GEMS_0" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox27" value="nervous">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox27">nervous</label>
  </div>
  <br />
</div>
<button id="checker">check selection</button>
```